# controlling two models separately

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, I found this simulation tutorial at: [VehicleSimulator](https://github.com/yukkysaito/vehicle_sim)
Am using ROS melodic.
Unfortunately only one of the worlds worked for me (world_test.launch).
Anyway, what am really interested in is creating another identical car model but control it separately from the one already spawned.
After following [this](https://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-130-how-to-launch-multiple-robots-in-gazebo-simulator/) tutorial, I managed to get the second model. but i can not control it (velocity and, if possible later on.  pid values).
So any advice on steps to follow so as to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346075/controlling-two-models-separately/) by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-07**:
How did you control the first robot? How are you trying to control the second one? Are you making sure that the  controllers have different names or namespaces?

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-03-09**:
hello. the first one is launched using the *world_test.launch* file from the repository provided in the *VehicleSimulator* link in the question. Am kind of lost as to which ones am supposed to give different names since its written in c++ and more familiar with python.
So, all i need to do is give the controllers different names or namespaces?
Or is there something else?
Thanks by the way.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-09**:
Looking at `rostopic list` after you start up the first robot, where do the topics for the controller action (often of type `follow_joint_trajectory`) appear? If you start up the second one, do they use a different topic? You can use either a different name or namespace the controller. The latter is usually simpler, but you need to connect whatever uses the controller's action to that topic, so you end up writing it out either way.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-03-13**:
thank you very much. indeed this was the issue. after making sure that they have different names and connected it all worked.
can you convert this to an answer so that i can accept it?

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-03-13**:
so now i can easily control their velocities (linear and angular separately). Does this apply to other controllers such as the PID, btw? or do i have to write different config.yaml, robot description files etc. ? thanks.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-16**:
I'm not sure I understand the question. It would be best if you could post a separate thread and link it here. Comments aren't meant for new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Summarizing the comments: You need to make sure that the controllers run in different namespaces (or have different names), so that they can be addressed separately.

Looking at rostopic list after you start up the first robot, you can check where the topics for the controller action (often of type follow_joint_trajectory) appear. If you start up the second one, do they use a different topic? You can use either a different name or namespace the controller. The latter is usually simpler, but you need to connect whatever uses the controller's action to that topic, so you end up writing it out either way.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0